# Map en JavaScript, recorrer, obtener claves y valores

Tags: javascript, map

Tengo creado un **Map** que tiene como *clave* un **string** y como *valor* un **arrays de strings**.

```
var miMapa = new Map();
miMapa.set("clave1", new Array("valor_a_1", "valor_a_2", "valor_a_3"));
miMapa.set("clave2", new Array("valor_b_1", "valor_b_2", "valor_b_3"));
miMapa.set("clave3", new Array("valor_c_1", "valor_c_2", "valor_c_3"));
```

He intentado recorrerlo así: (i es fija) (comparten las mismas keys)

```
var keys = Object.keys(miMapa);
for (var n = 0; n < keys.length; n++) {
    otroMapa.get(keys[n]).innerHTML = miMapa.get(keys[n])[i]; 
}
```

Pero no da resultado.
**¿Cómo se recorre un Map en JavaScript, cómo se obtiene su clave y cómo se obtiene el valor teniendo su clave?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si analizas la documentacion del `Map`

[Map Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map)

veras que puedes realizar un for

```
for (var [key, value] of miMapa) {
  alert(key + " = " + value);
}
```

En tu caso el `value` es un array por lo que deberias realizar un `for` mas para iterar por esos valores

Comment: Gracias, me guardo la documentación la desconocía.